# Record wav file for beyond verbal API

Tags: swift3, avaudioplayer

Hello Everone Hope you all are doing well

I have an issue regarding wav recording on iphone.able to record & store file but when i upload to [Beyond Verbal API](http://developers.beyondverbal.com/Home) then response is

> {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"status\":\"failure\",\"reason\":\"Bad
>   Wave format header Unknown\"}","status":400,"statusText":"Bad
>   Request"}

**MARK:- record audio path**

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

**MARK:- Start Recording with duration**

```
func startRecording() {
    let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("audioFile.wav")
    //        print(audioFilename)
    let settings = [

        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
        AVSampleRateKey: 41000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey:320000,
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey:16,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue

    ]

    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
        audioRecorder?.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
        audioRecorder?.record(forDuration: 15)
        audioRecorder.record()

    } catch {
        finishRecording(success: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is issue occur because of convert. So use **.m4a** file and then after go for convert into **.wav** file. it will work.